# Cannot assign method to variable php

Tags: php, oop

I have a public method on an external class

```
public function nextStep()
    {
        return $this->step++;
    }
```

The object `$this->step` is public

```
public $step;
```

I assign the value of it on the construct method

```
public function __construct($step)
    {
        $this->step = $step;
    }
```

I call this method from another class where i define

```
public $step = 0;
```

Then i do

```
$call = new StasisFlash\StasisFlash($this->step);
$nextStep = $call->nextStep();
```

That should return 1 but instead is returning 0. I've tried to print directly the `$call->nextStep()` and it returns 1 but if i try to assign the value to a variable or an object it returns 0, even if I print both at the same time

Appreciate any help

Comment: ```$i++``` returns ```$i``` before it increments. Whereas ```++$i``` returns ```$i``` after it increments. Perhaps try return ```++$this->step```;

Comment: _The object `$this->step is public`_ Do you mean the Property `$this->step` is public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `$i++` operator returns the value **before** it increments.

```
$i = 0;
echo $i++;
```

output: `0`

Whereas the `++$i` operator will return `$i` **after** it increments.

```
$i = 0;
echo ++$i;
```

output: `1`

---

To make your code more legible it may be better to add an extra line. It also removes any uncertainty in what you're trying to do.

```
public function nextStep()
{
  $this->step++;
  return $this->step;
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! this was the right answer, i don't know the need of everyone to downvote a question, if I knew it in the first place why do I bothered to ask?

Comment: @DouglasRoos It might be a good idea to include all your code as its difficult to know where you're declaring the variables and in what classes etc. Its a good question but perhaps the downvotes are because of that.

Comment: thanks, i will next time but on previous questions people here downvoted me for posting a lot of code =|

Comment: @DouglasRoos I think it comes down to posted the minimum amount of code required to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using `$this` is invalid. This suffix is only available inside the class scope.

Take a look at the following example.

```
class Duck
{
    // Set the default leg amount
    public $legs = 0;

    // This is called when creating a 'new Duck()' object
    public function __construct($legs = false)
    {
        // If a different amount of legs is set...
        if (false !== $legs) {
            $this->legs = $legs;
        }
    }
}

$duckOne = new Duck(5);

echo "The duck has ".$duckOne->legs." legs.";
// Returns: The duck has 5 legs.

$duckTwo = new Duck();

echo "The duck has ".$duckTwo->legs." legs.";
// Returns: The duck has 0 legs.
```

What you are essentially trying to do is:

```
echo $hello;
$hello = "Good day!";
```

You are using the `$this` while it does not exist.

```
Class Example
{
    public function method()
    {
        // You can only use $this here
    }
}

// You cannot use $this here because it is not defined
$example = new Example();
```